# Check html for updates every 15 minutes

Tags: android, html, updates

How do I check a html file on the internet if it has changed ? But it may not check the first 3 lines for the updates because it displays the time. The website does not use mysql or sqlite database. And is has not got a RSS feed system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you add this header line in the request:

```
If-Modified-Since: Sun Nov 6 08:49:37 1994
```

and then the server determines if the web page has changed since then, and return a 304 response if not. If the web page is generated by a CGI script, then it will be up to that script to decide if the page has changed.

Since you say the first three lines of the web page display the time, I assume the web page is generated by a CGI script of some sort. You haven't said what language that script is written in, but in any event, you'll need to grab the **If-Modified-Since** header from the request, parse the date, and decide if the content of the page has been modified since that date.

Comment: But what if the webserver doesnt support that?

Comment: If you're serving static contant and the webserver doesn't support *If-Modified-Since* for static content, then you're pretty much boned. If the content is generated by a CGI script, and the server doesn't allow CGI scripts to see the request headers, you're also boned. Otherwise, it's up to the CGI script to decide whether to return code 304 or not.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be every 15 minutes? If what you're really looking for is notification every time an HTML page changes, you should look at Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). This system generates a notification that's sent to your app by a server.

GCM has advantages that may not be obvious. The biggest one is battery life; constant polling drains the device battery. In comparison, GCM messages are received instantly while the device is connected to the network but not actively sending. In addition, GCM messages are queued and combined, so when the device is offline and then comes back online only one message is sent.

GCM also ensures that your app only uses the network when it has to get data. This allows other apps to use the network more readily.

Comment: No it doesnt need to be 15 minutes, it was just an example. but i dont want he app to check it every second because that takes loads of mb's